# loading dots using AnimationDrawable and XML shape

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want to made animation looks like that https://www.bensherman.co.uk/img/skin/loading.gif

Using xml shape files. For now on Ive have:
**EmptyDot XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">

    <size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>

    <solid android:color="#f214"/>
</shape>
```

**BiggerdotXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
        android:dither="true">

        <size android:height="15dip" android:width="15dip"/>

        <solid android:color="#f214"/>
    </shape>
```

**anim list XML**

```
 <animation-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="false" >

         <item android:drawable="@drawable/EmptyDot" android:duration="300" />

         <item android:drawable="@drawable/BiggerDot" android:duration="300"
             />

    </animation-list>
```

**MainActivity**

```
ImageView loadingDots = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadIngDots);
        final AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable
                = (AnimationDrawable)loadingDots.getDrawable();

        loadingDots.post(
                new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myAnimationDrawable.start();
                    }
                });
```

How can I store the XML views that can consist several Dot XML file that i can use in Animation list ? For example in my anim list XML I want to obtain somthing like that:

item 1 BiggerdotXML,EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML
item 2 EmptydotXML,BiggerdotXML,EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML
item 3 EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML,BiggerdotXML,EmptydotXML
item 4 EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML,EmptydotXML,BiggerdotXML

Comment: one quick and easy way to fix this , use .gif image of loading.no need to write code for animation .

Comment: Try an existing Library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3340.